# Program received signal "SIGABRT"

Tags: objective-c, ios4

hey guys i'm making an iphone app that uses the uipicker to get input from user. i have four different uipickers and separate arrays for them. 2 of the 4 arrays work. i am able to select values from them ! .However the other 2 one of them when clicked gives me the "SIGABRT' message and the other one once it gets to 8th element does the same !. here is my code  !

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    subtypepickerarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [subtypepickerarray addObject:@"hello"];
        [subtypepickerarray addObject:@"object 2"];
        [subtypepickerarray addObject:@"jfhgsjdfhg"];
        [subtypepicker reloadAllComponents];

    lymphnodearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int j = 0; j<=10;j++){
        NSString *answer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j];

        [lymphnodearray addObject:answer1];
        [Pos_lymppicker reloadAllComponents];

    }
}
```

and when i get the error message it highlights these codes

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
................
    else if (thePickerView == subtypepicker){

        return [subtypepickerarray objectAtIndex:row];

    }
    else {
        return[lymphnodearray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

after checking the output i found this

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

does that mean my array is empty ? i'm kinda confused ! any help would be appreciated ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your data source (in your case array) for UIPickerView has more items to be displayed then UIPicker expect. 
You need to work with this method to make it work fine

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSUInteger numRows;
    numRows = (NSUInteger)[yourArray count];
}
```

Comment: thanks guys ! :) i forgot to add a return in the  - '(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component'   and that was the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Array contains less objects than you are trying to access.

It has only 3 objects and you are trying to access 4 objects.

So please check the count of your array and fill the pickers accordingly.

Also check if your all 4 arrays are filled in properly with your data.

Hope this helps.